# Import text files with python using for loop

Tags: python

[Sample of .lvm file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11-GPCSnDgRQU00X2d4QUotdnVEaDVpY3BxbDVjUkpDQVFr)The files are .lvm format. The instructions given are:

*Using np.loadtxt to import the files, For full credit, import the three files using a for loop*

*Note, that you should skip the text lines in the header. Unpack the data into four columns: time (seconds), atmospheric pressure (kPa), temperature (degrees Celsius), and light intensity (lux).*

*Append the data together from these three imports, creating four 1D arrays for time, pressure, temperature, and light intensity.*

```
fname = ["Weather_Data_13-04-19_1306.lvm", "Weather_Data_13-04-20_1306.lvm", "Weather_Data_13-04-21_1306.lvm"]
dataframe = []
cols = ("time", "atm_pressure", "temp", "light_intensity")
for m in fname:
  for n in cols:
   cols[n] = np.loadtxt(fname[m], comments = '#', delimeter = None, skiprows = 0, unpack = True)

for i in fname:
  dataframe.append(np.loadtxt(i, unpack = True, skiprows = 21 ))
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-b95373bd7ba0> in <module>()
      7 
      8 for i in fname:
----> 9   dataframe.append(np.loadtxt(i, unpack = True, skiprows = 21 ))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in floatconv(x)
    779         if '0x' in x:
    780             return float.fromhex(x)
--> 781         return float(x)
    782 
    783     typ = dtype.type

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'X_Value'
```

I don't have an X_Value defined so I'm not sure how to address this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: show complete error message and .txt

Comment: ... and your data. See: [mcve].

Comment: I second that, need sample of lvm file to determine data format

Comment: sorry guys, first post. I updated it with the necessary information

Answer (score 0):

Skipping 21 rows leads to reading in the header; looks like you need to skip 22 rows instead.

Though, you may want to take a closer look at the LVM spec, in case `22` lines of headers isn't consistent accross files, i.e., there's almost certainly a better way to discard/use the header information.

Answer (score 0):

You seem like to have mistake in the using of "for loop "

```
for m in fname:
   for n in cols:
```

In this code, "m" and "n" are not index

So You must change your code like this.

```
for m in fname:
   for i in range(0, len(cols)):
       cols[i] = np.loadtxt(m,...
```